# how to render a variable in angular that contains html without adding an extra container?

Tags: html, angular, pipe

The idea, that is not working:

`<ng-container [innerHTML]="dataThatContainsHtml"></ng-container>`

The working code, but it adds an extra html element, that I want to avoid:

`<div class="avoid me" [innerHTML]="dataThatContainsHtml"></div>`

Any solutions on this?

I tried to use pipes with `DomSanitizer` and print it like this:

`{{ data | safeHTML }}`

But the Angular renders this text `SafeValue must use [property]=binding: ...`

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I've found a solution.

Code:

```
<div class="this div will not be rendered" [outerHTML]="dataThatContainsHtml"></div>
```

It will render `dataThatContainsHtml` without escaping HTML and will not render `div`